# j2me Lwuit form images from RSS feeds are not being loaded correctly

Tags: java-me, rss, lwuit

I have a LWUIT form in my j2me based application. I am getting my data through RSS Feeds(including image path). Now i want to show the images through RSS feeds image path in my LWUIT Form. I am using HTMLComponent for that purpose. The html based text is loading fine but the images are not being shown. Following is my code snippet.

```
             HTMLComponent htmlComp = new HTMLComponent();
             htmlComp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
             String imagePath=myItem.getImagePath().trim();
             htmlComp.setShowImages(true);
             String myHtml="<b>Hello</b> <br/> <img src= \""+imagePath+"\" /> ";
             System.out.println(myHtml);    
             htmlComp.setHTML(myHtml,null,null,false);
             addComponent(htmlComp);
```

The image path is like "http://toffeetv.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/f_swan-150x150.jpg".
Why the images are not being shown? Can anybody help me with an appropriate code example?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML Component accepts a base URL as one of its arguments to that method. Just set the URL to the appropriate path and it should work as expected.

Comment: HI,Even I'm also tried to display the image on LWUIT Form from Html String ,but I'm not able to display the image,Can you Provide me the sample code?